# Printing UTF-8 characters in R, Rmd, knitr, bookdown

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, knitr, bookdown

UPDATE (April 2018):
The problem still persists, under different settings and computers.
I believe it is related to all UNICODE, UTF-8 characters.

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

PROBLEM:

My Rmd/R file is saved with UTF-8 encoding. Other `sessionInfo()` details:

```
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.17
```

Here is a simple data frame that I need to print as a table in a html document, e.g. with `kable(dt)` or any other way.

```
dt <- data.frame(
name=c("Борис Немцов","Martin Luter King"),
year=c("2015","1968") 
)
```

Neither of the following works:

### Way 1

If I keep  Sys.setlocale() as is (i.e. `"English_Canada.1252"`), then I get this:

```
> dt;                                                                                           
name year
1 <U+0411><U+043E><U+0440><U+0438><U+0441> <U+041D><U+0435><U+043C><U+0446><U+043E><U+0432> 2015
2 Martin Luter King 1968
> kable(dt)
|name                                                                                      |year |
|:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|:----|
|<U+0411><U+043E><U+0440><U+0438><U+0441> <U+041D><U+0435><U+043C><U+0446><U+043E><U+0432> |2015 |
|Martin Luter King                                                                         |1968 |
```

Note that `<U+....>` are printed instead of characters.
Using `dt$name <- enc2utf8(as.character(dt$name))` did not help.

### Way 2

If I change `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")` #"Russian_Russia.1251"`, 
then I get this:

```
> dt; 
name year
1      Áîðèñ Íåìöîâ 2015
2 Martin Luter King 1968

> kable(dt)
|name              |year |
|:-----------------|:----|
|Áîðèñ Íåìöîâ      |2015 |
|Martin Luter King |1968 |
```

Note that characters have become gibberish.
Using `print(dt,encoding="windows-1251"); print(dt,encoding="UTF-8")` had no effect.

Any advice?

The closest I could find to address this problem are in the following links, but they did not help: http://blog.rolffredheim.com/2013/01/r-and-foreign-characters.html, https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows, https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets

I also tried to save my file with 1251 encoding (instead of current UTF-8 encoding) and some other character conversion/processing packages. Nothing helped yet.

UPDATE:

Opened related question:
[How to change Sys.setlocale, when you get Error "request to set locale … cannot be honored"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343831/how-to-change-sys-setlocale-when-you-get-error-request-to-set-locale-cannot)

Comment: I have no problems using my native locale `en_US.UTF-8` when printing to the console or knitting an HTML document. Using LaTeX is another story.

Comment: Thanks for trying - I tried to set my locale to what you have ` Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")` but got this error:
`OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored[1] ""` . This may explain why it works for you, but not for me (my local is `LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252`). So what can I do?

Comment: I fount two related suggested from knitr developer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703702/is-there-a-knitr-option-to-force-utf-8-encoding-in-included-r-files, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982566/rmarkdown-utf-8-error-on-mutliple-operating-systems . The idea is to move UTF-8 code in _separate file_ and then read it from there: `con = file("TestSpanishText.R", encoding = "UTF-8");
read_chunk(con);close(con) ` -

Comment: Can you try to set `Sys.setlocale(, "Russian")` in your `~/.Rprofile`? If you don't know what is `.Rprofile`, you may see https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html

Comment: Fantastisch! - I did that and printing with `print(dt)` still showed the same gibberish, however printing with` kable(dt)` produced exactly what is needed!        So conclusion - putting `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")` is not sufficient. You have to put it in .Rprofile and ...it works specifically with `kable()` (thanks to `knitr` developer :)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked was the one suggested by  Yihui Xie (`knitr` developer), which is :
creating a file `.Rprofile`, which contains one line `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")` and placing it in your home or working directory.

However, please note that, it works only with use of `kable()`, i.e with help of  `knitr` package.
If you try to print with `print(dt$name[1])`, you still get `Áîðèñ Íåìöîâ`.
However, if you use `kable(dt$name[1])`, you'll get what you need - `Борис Немцов` !