# How to change Sys.setlocale, when you get Error "request to set locale … cannot be honored"

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, knitr, r-markdown

This relates to the problem I'm trying to resolve here: [Printing UTF-8 (Russian) characters in R, Rmd, knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307007/printing-utf-8-russian-characters-in-r-rmd-knitr?noredirect=1#comment83625756_48307007).

I was told that this problem does not exist if native locale was `en_US.UTF-8`. (My current native locale is `English_Canada.1252`.)

But I cannot just simply change my English_Canada.1252 to en_US.UTF-8. - When I try I get this error message:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")
OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored[1] ""
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: You must be on Windows, and there is no UTF-8 locale on Windows.

Comment: Yes, it is Windows, And YX has just found solution for me for my main original question (on how to print UTF-8 in windows with knitr in Rmd)! So the answer for this question is no longer needed (for me at least now...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From above comments, this is not possible